# Problems compiling Kodi

Tags: 20.04, compiling

Well I´m pretty new on systems, but i wanted to start compiling my own programs instead of using the oficial repos. The thing is that I try to compile my own Kodi, so I followed the [oficial documentation](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/master/docs/README.Ubuntu.md) and the [Linux Build Guide](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/master/docs/README.Linux.md#41-configure-build). The problem starts on this second stage, when i reach the 3.1 Build missing dependencies, with the next command

> sudo make -C tools/depends/target/wayland-protocols PREFIX=/usr/local

When i type this comman I get the next error

> make: *** [makefile:39: native] error 127

I´ve been trying to catch what I´m doing wrong but I cant find nothing. Btw my OS is Ubuntu 20.4 Desktop with latest updates and upgrades

Comment: There is no such version as Ubuntu 20.4 A good start would be actually know the version number of the OS.

Comment: @David The version numbers is 20.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the Source Code repositories (*`deb-src`* in `/etc/apt/sources.list`) from Software & Updates applications, then get build dependencies for packaged [Kodi version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/kodi) by using command below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep kodi
```

and then proceed with long compilation. On the final stage use [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) by `sudo checkinstall` to create your own deb-package for installation instead of `sudo make install` which will lower future system manageability.